# Dynamically add Linearlayout to listviews

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I want to add a linearlayout to my listview dynamically on the press of a button. How should I do it? The linear layout contains an editText, a spinner and a label. This is the code for my adapter.

```
public class mBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;

public mBaseAdapter(Context c, ArrayList a)
{
    this.arrayList = a;
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    viewHolder v;
    if(view == null)
    {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.added, viewGroup, false);
        v = new viewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(v);
    }
    else
    {
        v = (viewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    return view;
}

private class viewHolder {
    TextView text;
    EditText edit1;
    Spinner spin1;

    public viewHolder(View item)
    {
        text = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        edit1 = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        spin1 = (Spinner) item.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    }

}
```

}

Am i on the right direction? How do I add a row on button click?

Comment: What does the code for your adapter look like?

Comment: That's whats confusing me. I was doing something like:  `ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>(...)`

Comment: Mmm, not quite. You could use a generic `ArrayAdapter`, but you would need the `getView()` method to return a `LinearLayout` with your EditText, Spinner, and label. It is easier to define a single "row" via an XML file, then just inflate that layout like you would for any custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

increment the model of the listview and populate a row based on that inside the adapter. Your row will contain spinner edit text and anything you like

Comment: Can u please elaborate?

Comment: post your code and i will tell you what to do. I would suggest you to read the working of a listview

Comment: Ok let me try if it.